# calculate disparity in processing

Tags: java, performance, processing, disparity-mapping

i'm using processing and  i'm trying to calculate disparity from 2 rectified images and for that i need to take every pixel from left image and seach in one line from right image and find the similar pixel ,the dimension of the images is 640x480 .

I need to run disparityImage(PImage imgL, PImage imgR) in function draw() and is too slow ,the function is execute in 1-2 seconds ,but if i comment these lines of code “minD=d;rightX=xr;” from the if block
the function is execute in 3-5 miliseconds. I don’t understand which is the problem with my code,i tried too many hours to find out but i couldn’t.

```
void depthImage(PImage imgL, PImage imgR) { 
    for (int x=0; x<imgL.width; x=x+1) {
      for (int y=0; y<imgL.height; y=y+1) {    
        color imgleft=imgL.get(x,y);
        float r1=red(imgleft);
        float g1=green(imgleft);
        float b1=blue(imgleft);

        float minD=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int rightX=0;

        for (int xr=0; xr<imgR.width; xr++) {    
          color imgright=imgR.get(x,y);
          float r2=red(imgright);
          float g2=green(imgright);
          float b2=blue(imgright);

          float d=dist(r1, g1, b1, r2, g2, b2);

          if (d<minD) {
            minD=d;
            rightX=xr;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

[`dist()`](https://processing.org/reference/dist_.html) calculates the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between 2 points. For the computation the [`sqrt()`](https://processing.org/reference/sqrt_.html) function is required. `sqrt()` is a very time consuming operation.

```java
dist(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2)
```

can be expressed as

```java
sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1) + (y2-y1)*(y2-y1) + (z2-z1)*(z2-z1))
```

I recommend to compute  and compare the square of the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) instead. That avoids the expensive `sqrt` operation. e.g.:

```java
void depthImage(PImage imgL, PImage imgR) {
    for (int x=0; x<imgL.width; x=x+1) {
        for (int y=0; y<imgL.height; y=y+1) {

            color imgleft = imgL.get(x,y);
            float r1=red(imgleft);
            float g1=green(imgleft);
            float b1=blue(imgleft);

            float minD_square = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int rightX=0;

            for (int xr=0; xr<imgR.width; xr++) {

                color imgright=imgR.get(x,y);
                float dr = red(imgright)   - r1;
                float dg = green(imgright) - g1;
                float db = blue(imgright)  - b1;

                float d_square = dr*dr + dg*dg + db*db;

                if (d_square < minD_square) {
                    minD_square = d_square;
                    rightX = xr;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```